# Facebook and Twitter API Rate Limit - Application Authentication depends on IP?

Tags: twitter, rate-limiting

The question seems duplicated, yet it's not. The question seems silly and it is. If I want to search for a certain word in tweets, I would send a request to the Twitter API. I can send the request:

1. Using user authentication: which requires logged in user.
2. Using application authentication: which doesn't require a logged in user and uses an application ID (public and private keys).

Now, Facebook, Twitter and other social networks for that matter provides API Rate Limit per user *and* per application (globally). Suppose that I want to search for the word "stackoverflow" from two application instances (one on iOS and the other on Android). Is the API limit *divided* on both of them? or each has its own full limit?

For example, assume that social network "X" provides up to 150 requests/app/15 min window. Do I have that 150 requests for each running instance of the application or I have a total of 150 requests for all instances?

Hope I made it clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [Question about app-only auth and rate limits for an iOS app in API v1.1](https://twittercommunity.com/t/question-about-app-only-auth-and-rate-limits-for-an-ios-app-in-api-v1-1/10974)

> The number of users or "instances of use" of your application are not figured in to rate limits for app-only auth. A method with a limit of 180 requests per 15 minute window is intrinsic to your application, regardless of whether it's on device A, device B, device C, website 1, website 2.